# Get UTC time for a particular date and time in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, datetime, utc

Helllo all,

I have a particular date & time selected from datepicker in iOS. i want to convert this date & time into UTC time.I have used below function for it.

```
func get_Date_time_from_UTC_time(string : String) -> String {

    let dateformattor = DateFormatter()
    dateformattor.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    dateformattor.timeZone = NSTimeZone.init(abbreviation: "UTC") as TimeZone!
    let dt = string
    let dt1 = dateformattor.date(from: dt as String)
    dateformattor.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ"
    dateformattor.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local
    return dateformattor.string(from: dt1!)
  }
```

My location is in india. So when i pass time like `2016-12-26 09:53:45` then it gives me UTC time as `2016-12-26 15:23:00 +0530`.Now when i search in google for UTC time it shows me time as `4:32 AM 26 december`.Please tell why is such diffrence & am i doing correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try using below code:
Because as per my understanding you should provide your local time zone first to convert your date into local and then it will convert into UTC:

```
func get_Date_time_from_UTC_time(string : String) -> String {

    let dateformattor = DateFormatter()
    dateformattor.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    dateformattor.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local
    let dt = string
    let dt1 = dateformattor.date(from: dt as String)
    dateformattor.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ"
    dateformattor.timeZone = NSTimeZone.init(abbreviation: "UTC") as TimeZone!
    return dateformattor.string(from: dt1!)
  }
```

I replaced timeZone code.Check and let me know if not solved

Comment: Strange both answers have exactly same code with same variable with seconds syncronization

Comment: Yes .. but you can check the time of answer :)

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are treating the date passed in parameter as UTC timezone, and asking it to be converted into Local Timezone. Instead you meant the opposite.

```
func get_Date_time_from_UTC_time(string : String) -> String {

    let dateformattor = DateFormatter()
    dateformattor.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    dateformattor.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local
    let dt = string
    let dt1 = dateformattor.date(from: dt as String)
    dateformattor.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ"
    dateformattor.timeZone = NSTimeZone.init(abbreviation: "UTC") as TimeZone!
    return dateformattor.string(from: dt1!)
}
```

Comment: Strange both answers have exactly same code with same variable with seconds syncronization

Comment: Yup, 13 sec difference.